# Installing PHP driver for Cassandra on MAMP

Tags: php, cassandra, mamp, mamp-pro

I'm running PHP 5.5.22 via MAMP (pro) on OSX 10.10.4 and I just want to use PHP to work with Cassandra (running locally).

Datastax seems to be the big boys of the Cassandra world. So I'm assuming I need to install this driver:  https://github.com/datastax/php-driver/ via these instructions: https://github.com/datastax/php-driver/blob/master/ext/README.md but they make no sense to me.

How can I get my cassandra.so module loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, got to it like this:

First I had to get my php on MAMP to be configured with the appropriate php source which does not ship with MAMP

1. I changed to the latest PHP version on MAMP, for me 5.6.10, also changed my PATH variables to the new bin for php: `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin/`
2. Downloaded the php 5.6.10 source, extracted it and renamed the folder to just ‘`php`’
3. Navigated to `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10` and created a directory called ‘`include`’ - copied the downloaded `php` folder in there
4. cd `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/include/php` and ran `./configure`

Then followed the instructions here: https://github.com/datastax/php-driver/blob/master/ext/README.md

1. In terminal, ran: `brew install libuv cmake gmp`
2. In a directory where in makes sense, run :

`git clone https://github.com/datastax/php-driver.git
cd php-driver
git submodule update --init
cd ext
./install.sh
phpize
./configure
make install`

Then edited the php.ini to add in: `extension=cassandra.so`